# What is the server IP in database trigger definitions?

Tags: database, trigger

We just did a MySQL server migration. I completely cleared out all the triggers and executed

> https://test.sdcbcdream.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/menu/rebuild&reset=1&triggerRebuild=1

This rebuilt the triggers. When I examine them, though, they all have for the definer field

> sdcbc@173.236.128.0/255.255.128.0

The IP for the new MySQL server is 208.97.161.77. Where is the rebuild trigger function getting the other IP? I believe that was the old IP, but am unsure as that server has been decommission by our host service.

We are running CiviCRM 5.10.3 on WordPress 5.1

Thanks for any help

Comment: Doesn't seem to be decommissioned. Seems like that's still a live block of IPs. Check what you have for the CIVICRM_DSN in civicrm.settings.php.

Comment: Interesting as I could not ping the old IP earlier. If I ping our CIVICRM_DSN host, mysql.sdbikecoalition.sdcbcdream.org it shows 208.97.161.77. It seems that the 173.236.128.0 seems hard-wired "somewhere" in our configuration.

Comment: Just to clarify, your domain is still test.sdcbcdream.org, which still points to a 173.x address, and only your mysql server has moved? And you're looking at the civicrm.settings.php file on the 173.x server?

Comment: Ah ... now I see my confusion.The websites we host are all on a 173.236.x address so that must be where that is coming from. Thanks for straightening me out. Yes, the MySQL server is separated from our web server. Should I just delete this post or do you think this thread might be useful to someone else? THANK YOU

Comment: This could be useful for others. That kind of split setup with a block of IPs can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to comments by Demerit, my confusion arises from the fact that our MySQL server and web server (with core CiviCRM files) are separate. The 173.236.128.0/255.255.128.0 mask matches our web server and so that definer field in the trigger just indicates the server from which the triggerRebuild command was executed. There was nothing wrong with our website operation. I just didn't understand the source of that IP, thinking it should match the IP of the MySQL server, which is wholly different. A good argument for a true VPS where you have full control of both Apache and MySQL on the same server.